# Parsing house number from street address represented as a char[]

Tags: c, arrays, char

Suppose I have a street address stored as a char[]. Examples of valid values:

- 1600 Pennsylvania Ave
- 1 Infinite Loop
- 221 Baker Street

As you can see, the house number can be of any length.

In C, what is an efficient way of separating the house number into its own int? I'm thinking I need to write a while loop to check for each char c if isdigit(c), but I don't know if I'm on the right track here in terms of implementation.

Comment: Consider using `sscanf`

Comment: @user3386109: My understanding is that sscanf is only useful for preformatted char[]'s, right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "preformatted char[]". `sscanf` can be used to extract the leading number from the strings in your question. If there is no leading number, `sscanf` will return 0.

Comment: Strtol? Scanf? Anything you're used to will work; what's the question?

Comment: ``  char address []="1600 Pennsylvania Ave";
  int num;
  sscanf (address,"%d",&num);``

Comment: Note that house number first may be the standard in English speaking countries, but elsewhere you'll often find it *after* the street name. Also watch out for streets whose *names* start with a number. But as long as there's a space or comma, this will work with sccanf.

Comment: It's also debatable whether storing the house number as an integer is a good idea. Often, house numbers have som non-numerical parts, like "165 bis" or "51/IV", so a character array might be a better data type. (After all, Sherlock Holmes's address is "221B Baker St".)

Answer (score 0):

You can use strtok to break up the string into tokens and use isdigit() to figure out if that token is numeric.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   const char str1[80] = "1600 Pennsylvania Ave";
   int houseNumber = 0;
   const char s[2] = " ";
   char *token;

   /* get the first token */
   token = strtok(str, s);

   /* walk through other tokens */
   while( token != NULL ) {
      printf( " %s\n", token );
      if (isdigit(str1[0])) {
           houseNumber = atoi (token);
      }
      token = strtok(NULL, s);
   }

   return(0);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use sscanf to read the entire string and automatically parse everything:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
   const char str1[80] = "1600 Pennsylvania Ave";
   int houseNumber = 0;
   char streetName[50];
   char streetExt[20]; 

   sscanf (str1,"%d %s %s", &houseNumber, streetName, streetExt);

   return(0);
}
```

This last method depends on the format of the strings being exactly the same in all cases, meaning that it's always a number followed by 2 strings.  The strtok method will be a little more fault tolerant if there's more other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following solution:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char address[255];
    char * ptr;
    int number;
    char strnumber[100];
    char strstreet[255];
    // ask adress
    printf("Please, enter the addres: ");
    // put end of string replacing newline
    fgets(address, 255, stdin);
    ptr = strchr(address, '\n');
    if(ptr)
    {
        *ptr = '\0';
    }
    else
    {
        address[254] = '\0';
    }

    // try to read whole number from the beggining of the string
    if( 1 == sscanf(address, "%d", &number) )
    {
        // make number as a string (if it is needed)
        sprintf(strnumber, "%d", number);
        // take streat to separate string
        ptr = strchr(address + strlen(strnumber), ' '); // find the firs space
        if( ptr )
        {
            strcpy(strstreet, ptr + 1); // +1 just to skip the found space
        }
    }
    else
    {   // if no number at the beginning of address string
        number = 0;
        strnumber[0] = '\0';
        strstreet[0] = '\0';
    }
    // show the results
    printf("You have entered a string:\n%s\n", address);
    printf("The found number is:\n%d\n", number);
    printf("The found number as a string:\n%s\n", strnumber);
    printf("The address without number is:\n%s\n", strstreet);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use strstr and atoi like this

```
char someAddress[80] = "1600 Pennsylvania Ave";
char* p = strstr(someAddress, " ");
if (p)
{
    *p = 0;    // Terminate string, i.e. cheat for a moment
    int number = atoi(someAddress);
    *p = " ";  // Restore someAddress
}
else
{
     // Handle illegal format in someAddress
}
```

This method shall only be used when you know it is safe to modify someAddress for a short period.

Answer (score 0):

This is one situation with the numbers first, where it is much easier just to use a simple pointer and an `if` statement to parse the line:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define ADDL 64

int main (void) {

    char address[ADDL] = {0};
    char street[16] = {0};

    while (fgets (address, ADDL-1, stdin) != NULL) 
    {
        char *ap = address;
        char *sp = street;

        while (*ap >= '0' && *ap <= '9')  /* while the char is a number */
        {
            *sp = *ap++;                  /* copy to street number      */
            sp++;
        }
        *sp = 0;                          /* null-terminate             */

        printf (" Address: %s Number : %s\n\n", address, street);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/split_address < dat/houses.txt
 Address: 1600 Pennsylvania Ave
 Number : 1600

 Address: 1 Infinite Loop
 Number : 1

 Address: 221 Baker Street
 Number : 221
```

**Note:** the `printf` statement above makes use to the embedded `newline` at the end of `address` rather than stripping it as you would normally do. Also **note** that if you want the number as an `integer`, `long`, or `unsigned`, simply call `atoi`, `strtol` or `strtoul` on `street`.